# Strange jQuery problem

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

The jQuery below gets a partial view containing a html table of addresses. jqModal is then used to display the addresses, and a mouseover used to highlight an address. This works fine on my local machine. When I try running it from a server (Win 2008, IIS 7), the addresses are shown in jqModal but the higlighting fails to work. Also, this works fine when browsing from the server.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#Search").click(function() {
        displayAddressList();
    });
    $('#dialog').jqm();

});


function displayAddressList() {
   var PostCode = $("#tbSearch").val();
   var url = '<%= Url.Action("AddressSearch", "Addresses")%>';
   $.get(url, { PostCode: PostCode }, function(data) {
   $("#dialog").html(data);

       $('table#data_table tr').mouseover(function() {
           $(this).addClass('selectedRow');
       }).mouseout(function() {
           $(this).removeClass('selectedRow');
       });   

   }); 
}
</script>

<style>  
  .selectedRow {   
     background-color: white;   
     cursor: pointer;   
  }   
</style>  

<div class="jqmWindow" id="dialog">
    <a href="#" class="jqmClose">Close</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks like it only works if the host is localhost... Does the AJAX request actually execute?

Comment: So what does <%= Url.Action("AddressSearch", "Addresses") %> render to when it's sent to the client? Your app isn't running in a virtual directory on the live site or anything?

Comment: A partial view that creates a html table of addresses

Comment: What browser are you using to view this?

Comment: Internet Explorer 8, on both the client and the server

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about Internet Explorer 6 support, you can implement row highlighting in CSS instead.

```
#data_table tr:hover {
  background-color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

If you do this, make sure to have a valid DOCTYPE declaration at the top of your HTML pages.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

Comment: When the user clicks the row I will then be using jQuery to update textboxes on the page and close the jqModal window.

Comment: @Danny - you can still use jQuery for handling the clicks, etc. but as Wesley says, it might be easier to just use CSS for the row highlighting

Answer (score 1):

You say only the highlight fails to work. Generally, you'd want to use jQuery's `live` function for that: http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live - it is meant to bind event after ajax calls (or other DOM changes). You'll only have to call this once at `$(document).ready`, instead of every time you load the data.

Another common option is that you have more than one `#data_table` on the page (maybe hidden), jQuery will only find the first one.

Comment: Click function on the row also failing.

Comment: Failing, or not starting at all? (btw, you didn't post any click function) Did you try it with the live function? You'd have simpler code that way, too.

Comment: Not live function yet, will do though. I placed an alert after  $(this).addClass('selectedRow'); which does not fire.

Answer (score 1):

I would agree with DrJokepu: it looks as though your Ajax is requesting data from localhost (hence it only working on your dev machine or when browsing on the server).

Can you check the Ajax requests in something like [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) (or [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) for IE) to see if they are actually being made?

Comment: For watching web traffic the wonderful tool HttpFox: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6647 is excellent.

Comment: The table of addresses is being returned from the Ajax request and is displayed in the jqModal window.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it doesn't like:

```
$('table#data_table tr')
```

Try changing that selector to just:

```
$('#data_table tr')
```

Otherwise, try using different CSS properties, maybe those particular ones are not getting applied. Of course, this could all be **way** off, but it can't hurt to try.

Comment: $('table#data_table tr') should work. If it doesn't, that's a bug either in jQuery or the browser, but I would be really surprised if that were the case.

Comment: I know, it's seems more likely that it's to do with CSS. I just listed the things I would try, as *unlikely* seems to bite me a lot these days :)

Comment: Worth a try, but did'nt sort it

Comment: I honestly don't know what else to suggest. I'll delete this answer once & if this question gets satisfactorily answered.

Answer (score 0):

i would add some alerts so you can see if anything is actually happening. also you've got your css set to background:white - so will you actually see anything change - should it be a colour?!

Josh

Comment: The jqModal window is not white, so you can see the highlighting